# Use list comprehension to return a new list

Tags: python

I have a dict array that I want to get a specific attribute and create a new dict list based on those attribute.

I'm trying to use list comprehension to parse every row instead of use a traditional loop. Is possible to do it?

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse


def _format_string_to_timestamp(dt, output):
    if dt is None or type(dt) == float:
        return ""
    origin_dt = parse(dt)
    return origin_dt.strftime(output)

def extract_tickets_tags_history(audit):
    tag_history = []
    sync = "1234"
    tags = [d for d in audit['events'] if d.get('field_name', '') == 'tags']
    if len(tags) > 0:
        return [
            {
                'tag': tag,
                'updated': _format_string_to_timestamp(audit['created_at'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                'ticket_id': audit['ticket_id'],
                'tagged': False,
                'user_id': audit['author_id'],
                'sync': sync
            } 
            for tag in tags[-1]['value']]
    return None

audit = {
    'ticket_id': 123,
    'author_id': 654,
    'created_at': '2019-04-07T01:09:40Z',
    'events': [
        {
            'field_name': 'tags',
            'value': ['taga', 'tagb']
        }
    ]
}

example = [
    {
        'id': 123,
        'data': [audit]
    }
]

result = [extract_tickets_tags_history(data) for data in x['data'] for x in example]
```

I'm getting an error `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`
...
And the result should be something like `[{"tag": "...", "updated": "...", ...}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swapped the two for loops in your list comprehension

```
result = [extract_tickets_tags_history(data) for x in example for data in x['data'] ]
```

which is equivalent to

```
result = []
for x in example:
    for data in x['data']:
        result.append(extract_tickets_tags_history(data))
```

Comment: Is possible to get a single array instead of [[{...}]]?

Comment: I addressed your error `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` , you might want to add the defintion of `_format_string_to_timestamp` to begin with, also what is `[[{.....}]]` ?

Comment: Yes! It solved the error `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` but I would like to have a single list instead of `[[{'tag': 'taga', 'updated': '2019-04-07 01:09:40', 'ticket_id': 123, 'tagged': False, 'user_id': 654, 'sync': '1234'}, {'tag': 'tagb', 'updated': '2019-04-07 01:09:40', 'ticket_id': 123, 'tagged': False, 'user_id': 654, 'sync': '1234'}]]`. Probably I need to flat the result

Comment: I've added definition of `_format_string_to_timestamp`

Comment: Solved it `result = [banana for x in example for data in x['data'] for banana in extract_tickets_tags_history(data) ]`

Comment: Great! Glad to solved it yourself @placplacboom :) If the answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted :)